# SQL Query for Logins

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the SQL query to select all of the MSSQL Server's logins?

Thank you.  More than one of you had the answer I was looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM syslogins
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
select * from master.syslogins
```

Comment: Starting with SQL 2008, you should use [sys.server_principals instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx)

Answer (score 49):

On SQL Azure as of 2012;

logins:

```
    --connecct to master

    --logins
    SELECT * from sys.sql_logins
    --users
    SELECT * from sys.sysusers
```

and users on a specific database:

```
    --connect to database
    SELECT * from sys.sysusers
```

Also note that 'users' on Azure SQL now (2022-11-17) have more 'login' type properties and creating a user on a Azure SQL database with a password is now possible, so it is less likely to require creating logins in 'master'.

Comment: "master" would be replaced by the name of your database, assuming you are targeting one specifically.

Comment: "SELECT * from master.sys.sql_logins" does not work.  I get this error: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.sql_logins' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: since logins are server-wide, it's not necessary to specify DB name: `SELECT * from sys.sql_logins`

Comment: `Invalid object name 'sys.sql_logins'.` and `Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.sql_logins' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.`

Comment: Use `SELECT * from sys.server_principals` instead

Comment: @HenrikHøyer `sys.server_principals` only lists entries with the `##MS_Database...` and `##MS_Server...` prefix without any of the Server Logins listed by SSMS, for that I need to query `sys.sql_logins` which is only accessible when connected to the (virtual) `master` database.

Answer (score 18):

```
EXEC sp_helplogins
```

You can also pass an "@LoginNamePattern" parameter to get information about a specific login:

```
EXEC sp_helplogins @LoginNamePattern='fred'
```

Answer (score 9):

Starting with SQL 2008, you should use [`sys.server_principals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) instead of `sys.syslogins`, [which has been deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx).

Comment: guidance on new mappings from other depcreated tables can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 4):

@allain, @GateKiller your query selects users not logins
To select logins you can use this query:

```
SELECT name FROM master..sysxlogins WHERE sid IS NOT NULL
```

In MSSQL2005/2008 syslogins table is used insted of sysxlogins

Answer (score 4):

Selecting from sysusers will get you information about *users* on the selected database, not *logins* on the server.

Answer (score 4):

sp_helplogins will give you the logins along with the DBs and the rights on them.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * From Master..SysUsers Where IsSqlUser = 1
```

Comment: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master..syslogins' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the syslogins or sysusers tables in the master schema. Not sure if this still still around in more recent MSSQL versions though. In MSSQL 2005 there are views called sys.syslogins and sys.sysusers.