# How to extract a list of all users and logins with fixed server roles

Tags: sql-server

Good evening. How do I extract the list of all users and logins with fixed server roles. In a nutshell i need a list of all logins and users that have access to the DBs and instance with the following fields:
DB_DataReader
DB_DataWriter
DB_DenyDataWriter
DB_DenyDataReader

thanks

Comment: Is this question possibly related to what you are wanting? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275/sql-query-for-logins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275/sql-query-for-logins)

Comment: Yes it is, but I need those fields. I know for sure there is a query with these fields, I have extracted before, but I can't recall now.

Comment: found it:USE live
select rp.name as database_role, mp.name as database_user
from sys.database_role_members drm
join sys.database_principals rp on (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
join sys.database_principals mp on (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)